# Messages are coming up blank?

Tags: ios, swift, email, post, message

I've got some code that takes text from a text box and sends it through a POST message to a server, which then sends it to an email address.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func sendEmail() {

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.fakewebsite.com/email.php")
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
    NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

    // set data
    var dataString = emailText.text
    let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

    // set content length
    //NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

    let results = NSString(data:reply!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("API Response: \(results)")
}

@IBAction func sendButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    sendEmail()
    println(emailText.text)
}
}
```

The email comes through when the button is pressed but there's nothing in the email, it's just blank. Yes, there is text in the text field. Can you see where I might be going wrong?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it will help because I feel like even if it was optional the text would still get sent, but try unwrapping the text in the text box because that's technically an optional property

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why your text might not be coming up:

--> The mapping between your storyboard and you ViewController is somehow severed. Try reconnecting them.

--> You can try and specifically use "self"

```
var dataString = self.emailText.text;
```

--> You could use the following initializer provided by NSData:

```
NSData(base64String:String, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions)
```

--> place a debug point or write a simple print statement showing what is the length of the data that is present:

```
let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
//if this print says length is 0 then you dont seem to a valid link between the storyboard and the ViewController
print(requestBodyData.length)
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
try something like this

```
    let postRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "")!)
    let postBody = NSMutableData()

    postRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // Boundary & Charset
    let boundary = "blahblahblah"
    let charset = "utf-8"

    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; charset=\(charset); boundary=\(boundary)"
    postRequest.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let stringData = NSMutableString()

    stringData.appendFormat("--\(boundary)\r\n")

    let endBound = "\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n"
    let codeInfo = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"code\"\r\n\r\n\(code!)"
    stringData.appendString(codeInfo)
    stringData.appendString(endBound)

    postBody.appendData(stringData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    postRequest.HTTPBody = postBody

    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(postRequest, queue: operationQueue) { (response, data, error) -> Void in
        if data != nil {
            let resp = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Response -> \(resp)")


        }
    }
```

//-----

Try debuging your code and see if you really have text in 'dataString'.
Also make sure 'requestBodyData' is not nil

If its nil or empty that probably means emailText of your storyboard is not properly connected with the code '@IBOutlet'

```
// set data
var dataString = emailText.text
let requestBodyData = (dataString as  NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

or may be check like this

```
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=\(boundary)"
request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: When I press the button the following comes up in the console: 4, API Response: Optional(), Text (this is what I put into the text box). The 4 is requestBodyData number.